# Custom node color from role

Tags: 7, nodes

How to create custom node background color from role id
e.g. admin - **red**
manager -**green**
auth user - **blue**, automatically?

Find examples (template.php)

```
function themename_preprocess_node($variables) {
  $account = user_load($variables['user']->uid);
  //$account = user_load(array('uid' => $node->uid));
  $user_roles = $account->roles;
  if (in_array('administrator', $user_roles)) {
    $my_class = 'user-admin';
  }
  elseif (in_array('authenticated user', $user_roles)) {
    $my_class = 'user-author';
  }
  elseif (in_array('test user remove', $user_roles)) {
    $my_class = 'user-power-author';
  }
  elseif (in_array('VIP', $user_roles)) {
    $my_class = 'vip-author';
  }
  if (isset($my_class)) {
    $variables['attributes_array']['class'][] = $my_class;
  }
}
```

This doesn't work

Comment: background color for the <body> tag or any other div ?

Comment: Current user's role or Author's role ?

Comment: I find example:

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** From the code you've added it looks like you want to add the class based on the node author. You can use much the same principle:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $account = user_load($vars['node']->uid);

  foreach ($account->roles as $role) {
    $vars['classes_array'][] = 'role-' . strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $role));
  }
}
```

Each node will have the `role-rolename` classes added to it (see original answer below).

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Quick and easy way:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  global $user;

  // Loop over the user's roles and add a class to the body class array.
  foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
    $vars['classes_array'][] = 'role-' . strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $role));
  }
}
```

That adds classes like `role-administrator` and `role-authenticated-user` (and any other roles the user has) to the `<body>` tag. From there you should be able to target things easily with CSS (e.g. `body.role-manager{background:red}`).

Remember to clear Drupal's caches after you've added the preprocess function, or the changes won't get picked up.

Comment: Perfectly. Everything works. Once again many thanks.