# Profile picture with a border color depending of the role

Tags: views, blocks, media, users

Is there any way to set a border color to every profile picture displayed all over the website depending on the role of the user?

I was trying to do it at least on the user profile image and on the User picture block module image following this instructions [Custom node color from role](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41662/custom-node-color-from-role) but I ended in nothing.

Note: I display the profile pictures in a user search view, in the forums and in a block that display the latest forum comments.

Answer (score 1):

Try [hook_preprocess_user_picture()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/template_preprocess_user_picture/7) in your template.php

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_user_picture(&$vars) {
    $account = user_load($vars['account']->uid);

    foreach ($account->roles as $role) {
        $vars['classes_array'][] = 'role-' . strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $role));
    }
}
```

Each user picture should then have the **role-rolename** classes added to it.
It is similar to [Clive's answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/41665/2792) you mentioned, but different hook.

Comment: Sorry but this is not working, my user pictures are displayed using views (a list of users), profile (using a DS module template), forums (author pane) and user-picture-block module so all of them have classes different that "user-picture", well in fact one does but it doesn't get the "role-" class anyway... none of my pictures are getting the role, neither if you go to edit a user (with the admin 1)...

Answer (score 0):

I partially solved the problem with this:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$vars){
    global $user;

  foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
    $vars['classes_array'][] = 'role-current-' . strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $role));
  }

  if(arg(1) && arg(0)=='user'){
      $account=user_load(arg(1));
      foreach ($account->roles as $role) {
            $vars['classes_array'][] = 'role-visited-' . strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $role));
        }
  }
}
```

with this CSS:

```
.role-current-beta-tester .content_left .user_picture_block img,
.role-visited-beta-tester .user-profile .field-name-ds-user-picture img{
    border: 17px #019E96 solid;
    background: white;
}

.role-current-moderator .content_left .user_picture_block img,
.role-visited-moderator .user-profile .field-name-ds-user-picture img{
    border: 17px #37A962 solid;
    background: white;
}

.role-current-administrator .content_left .user_picture_block img,
.role-visited-administrator .user-profile .field-name-ds-user-picture img{
    border: 17px #517180 solid;
    background: white;
}

.role-current-usuario-profesional .content_left .user_picture_block img,
.role-visited-usuario-profesional .user-profile .field-name-ds-user-picture img{
    border: 17px #8A101C solid;
    background: white;
}

.role-current-usuario-no-profesional .content_left .user_picture_block img,
.role-visited-usuario-no-profesional .user-profile .field-name-ds-user-picture img{
    border: 17px #A8CE3D solid;
    background: white;
}
```

but that only works for the border of the picture displayed by the user-picture-block module and the picture of each user's profile (formatted with Display Suite). I still have the problem of the forums, my user search view and a small block that display user's latest comments on the forums (the default one of Advanced Forum module).